# Mod rewrite doesn't work when I added multiple domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have Redhat Linux server and I was using `/var/www/html` to display my site.

By using the following directive rewrite mod was working fine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Enable mod_rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine on

  # WITH mandatory 'www.'
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$uri\.$tld$ [NC]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.$domain$1 [L,R=301]

  # WITHOUT 'www.'
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.$uri\.$tld$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$domain/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

After the addition of

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domainmaster.example
ServerAlias domainmaster.example *.domainmaster.example
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainmaster
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domainother.example
ServerAlias domainother.example *.domainother.example
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainother
</VirtualHost>
```

URL rewrite doesn't work. Website files wasn't modified. `.htaccess` file redirects all traffic to `index.php` and `index.php` decides which page to display.

Comment: What are `$uri`, `$tld` and `$domain`? These domains are presumably intended to be separate (different .htaccess files etc)?

Comment: i think it's for multiple domains support.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you place the `mod_rewrite` directives that you have provided?

If you still have those directives in `httpd.conf`, then, perhaps, they fall outside of the `VirtualHost` directives, and have no effect on your vhost domains?